# ValidationAttribute with conditional argument value

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, attributes

I am new to ValidationAttributes.  I would like to develop a ValidationAttribute subclass (MustExistAttribute) that works one of two ways, depending on a run-time situation.  For example, I have a class called RECORD with a property called KEY and I want the validation test to be something like, "look up this KEY in the database and see if it exists".

However, that alone is not enough.  I also need to test another property (RECORD.IsNew).  Then, if that also is true, the fact that this KEY exists is an error, but if RECORD.IsNew is false, then, validation should pass.  In other words, the attribute's IsValid override needs access not only to the value that the framework automatically supplies (KEY), but also to RECORD (or RECORD.IsNew).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to my question is "No".  But there is a work-around.

At the point where the validations have been applied, i.e., where I would normally have something like

`if( ModelState.IsValid)`

, I can add whatever test I want and then use something like

`ModelState.AddModelError( "KEY", "The database already has a record for the new KEY." );`

AddModelError will set IsValid to false, so I can retest and go from there.  The framework treats my new error just as it does all the others, associating it with the KEY property.